# is it legit to establish a relationship between two subclasses which sharing the same superclass (IS-A relationship)?

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, erd

I have a question regarding a project I am doing and hope you could provide some help:)

The police were looking for a murder suspect after a person was shot and killed yesterday. The only clue is that the victim has left a note with five people's names on it, and the police needed to find these five people's information by searching on the citizen database (name is not unique so there may be more than five results. To uniquely identify someone you need the citizen ID). After finding the murderer, the police need to make changes to the murderer's criminal record. I am wondering how could I do this?

Since the entity Victim and the entity Murder_suspects both have the same attributes as the entity Citizen, my original plan was to make victim and murder_suspects become two subclasses sharing the same superclass(citizen), that is to say, victim ISA citizen and murder_suspects ISA citizen. However, I am not sure if it is legit to establish a relationship between two subclasses which share the same superclass (IS-A relationship). Also, I think the primary key of murder_suspects should be citizen.name instead of citizen.id, but I don't think that the subclass's primary key could be different from its superclass's primary key. I am wondering if anyone could help with my confusion and give me some suggestions, thanks in advance:)!

P.S. To make it more clear, the entity citizen has the following attributes: id, name, phone_number, address, criminal_record, etc.

Many thanks for any help anyone is able to provide:)

Answer (score 1):

```
Citizen
-------
Id
FirstName
LastName
DateOfBirth
Sex

Address
------
Id
Street
House
City

Case
----
Id
Name
Date

Victim
-------
Id
CitizenId
CaseId
SomeUniqueToVictimProperty

Suspect
-------
Id
CitizenId
CaseId
SomeUniqueToSuspectProperty
```

> Also, I think the primary key of murder_suspects should be citizen.name instead of citizen.id

I would stick to CitizenId not CitizenName. Its faster to look by int/bigint than by varchar/text. Also I would add Id as a PK in both victim and suspect because after some time with more and more cases you would have a problem: everyone can commit only one crime because citizen record is already in "suspect" table under another case? You might make two column PK (CitizenName + CaseId), but why?
I wouldn't connect victim to a suspect. You may connect victim to a crime and suspect to a crime. There is nothing that links them directly. Case is linking them so stick to reality.

> the entity citizen has the following attributes: id, name, phone_number, address, criminal_record, etc.

1. Maybe that too much but how about putting address to another table?
   what if someone has two addresses? of two different kinds?
2. Phone number might be in address or in "Contact" table?
3. Criminal_record? with what? enormous text of all crimes? I would
   stick to relations to "suspect" table or something like that